# What's the differences between the iPod Touch calendar and the iPhone calendar?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, calendar

What's the differences between the iPod Touch calendar and the iPhone calendar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. What makes you think there is?

Comment: I've heard before the launch that would have less functions.. long time ago, but I remembered now, that I'm wanting to buy one..

Comment: I see. The differences you heard about would have been related to apps or functions requiring hardware only found on the iPhone (cell data, voice calls, SMS, etc). Luckily apps such as the Calendar, Clock, Mail, etc. all work in exactly the same way.

Comment: Well, back at launch, the iPod touch did not have Mail or Calendar; they were added in January of 2008 with the 1.1.3 update.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running the same version of iOS, there should be absolutely no difference whatsoever.